# How to print items of class including os('clear')?

Tags: python, class, oop, printing

Can somebody explain to me why the menu() function in the code below does not print the attributes of the class person while menu2() does?

Thank you

```
import os
class person():
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def printAttr(self):
        print([self.name, self.age])


def menu(title = None):
    while True:
        os.system('clear')
        print("A")
        title
        break

def menu2(title = None):
    while True:
        print("A")
        title
        break

Person = person("Peter", 35)
menu(title=Person.printAttr())
print("")
menu2(title=Person.printAttr())
```

Comment: You print the attributes *before* you call any of the menu functions; `menu` then clears the screen, while `menu2` leaves the screen as is.

Comment: You also understand that `title` inside the menu functions doesn't do anything, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you set the title, you also print the attributes. You then move into menu() where you clear the output.

If you insist on using os.system('clear') you could change your code to the following:

```
def menu(title = None):
    while True:
        os.system('clear')
        print("A")
        title.printAttr()
        break

Person = person("Peter", 35)
menu(title=Person)
```

In the above solution, you print after the console clear, using the printAttr() inside the methode, instead of when you set the title parameter.